# Left and right coset calculation for matrix

Tags: group-theory

If $$
G = \left\{ 
\begin{pmatrix} c & a \\
0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} c,a\in (\mathbb{R}) : c \neq 0
\right\} 
$$
and assume G is a group under matrix multpication
$$
 H = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & x \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}: x\in\mathbb{R} \right\}
$$
Find  the left and right cosets of H in G and show that they are equal

So far I have done the following:
$gH = \begin{pmatrix} c & a \\
0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & x \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

$=\begin{pmatrix} c & cx+a \\
0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

To calculate the right coset, choose $g' =\begin{pmatrix} c' & a' \\
0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, c' a' \in G$:

Then $Hg'=\begin{pmatrix} c' & x+a' \\
0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

How does $gH$=$Hg'$ in this case?

Comment: The second to last sentence doesn't look good. Is it $g$ or $g^\prime$?

Comment: You say that $gH= \begin{pmatrix}c & cx+ a \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$.  What does this **mean**?  That is, since the only condition here is that a, c, and x be real numbers, how is this different from  general matrix in G?

Comment: Hint: take $h=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & (b-a)/c\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\in H$. Then $gh=\begin{pmatrix} c & b\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Note that you have to prove $g H = H g$ for each $g \in G$.

Comment: well haven't I, since both the left and right coset both depend only on 1 variable (x), doesn't that make them equal?